# Can't convert date/time string into date

Tags: swift3, date-formatting

The conversion from string to date keeps returning nil:

```
if let dateString = dict["dateScanned"] as? String {
       let strTime = dateString // 9/5/2017 12:00:00 AM
       let formatter = DateFormatter()
       formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
       let myDate = formatter.date(from: strTime)  // myDate = nil
       print(myDate)
   }
```

Comment: The date format doesn't match. 12-hour format with am/pm is `"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"` (note lowercase `h` and trailing `a`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the AM/PM information:

```
formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"
```

<sup>(and you have to use lower case hh, as pointed out by vadian)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for that!  I can't mark as solved for another few minutes. Quick question though  the date is stored in the database in UTC.  When I converted the date, it took a date that was already in UTC format, and converted it once again to UTC adding four hours.  How can I format to EST?

Comment: The date is correct. The date formatter considers the local time zone, however `print` shows the date always in UTC.

Comment: Thanks vadian!  I just spent an hour converting a date.  Not a great way to start the day!